# Why removing std::cout before inline assembly triggers Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_I386_DIV, subcode=0x0)

Tags: c++, xcode, inline-assembly

I've wrote cpp code that uses inline assembly to calculate z = x/(y-7) and w = x%(y-7):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    unsigned int x = 28, y = 12, z, w;
    
    std::cout << "result: " << std::endl;
    asm (
         "movl   (%[pX]), %%eax\n\t"
         "movl   (%[pY]), %%ebx\n\t"
         "subl   $7, %%ebx\n\t"
         "divl   %%ebx\t"
         :"=a"(z), "=&d"(w)
         :[pX]"r"(&x), [pY]"r"(&y)
         :"cc"
         );
    
    std::cout << "z = " << z << std::endl;
    std::cout << "w = " << w << std::endl << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output is correct:

```
result: 
z = 5
w = 3

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

But when I remove `std::cout << "result: " << std::endl;` line I've got a `Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_I386_DIV, subcode=0x0)` in  `asm (` which is division by zero error

I'm running this code in Xcode 14.3 on Intel Mac

Comment: Apparently `std::cout << endl` happens to leave a `0` in EDX before your asm statement, so it happens to work.

Comment: Note: Standard C++ has no provision for inline ASM. Your code is not portable and compiler specific.